# stylescombo plugins with multiple class selection

Tags: ckeditor

I merged the stylesheetparser and the stylescombo plugins and want to select mutiple classes from the combo. I made some changes in the onOpen and the onClick functions:

```
onOpen: function() {
    var selection = editor.getSelection(),
        selectedElement = selection.getSelectedElement(),
        selectedRanges = !selectedElement && selection.getRanges(),
        selectedText = !selectedElement && selection.getSelectedText(),
        nativeRange,
        elementPath = editor.elementPath(),
        element,
        counter = [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ];

    this.showAll();
    this.unmarkAll();
    for ( var name in styles ) {
        var style = styles[ name ],
            type = style._.type;

        if(type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_OBJECT && (selectedElement || selectedText))
            element = !selectedText ? selectedElement : selectedText;

        else if((type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_BLOCK || type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE) && !selectedText && !selectedElement && selectedRanges[ 0 ] && selectedRanges[ 0 ].getCommonAncestor( 1 ))
            element = selectedRanges[ 0 ].getCommonAncestor( 1 ).getAscendant( style.element );

        else if(type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE && selectedText && !selectedElement)
            element = selectedText;

        if(element != null) {
            if(style.checkApplicable( elementPath, editor, editor.activeFilter )) {
                counter[ type ]++;

                var classes = !selectedText ? element.getAttribute( 'class' ) : null,
                    classArr = classes != null ? classes.split(' ') : [];

                if(classArr.length > 0) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < classArr.length; i++) {
                        if(classArr[i] == style._.definition.attributes['class'])
                            this.mark( name );
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                this.hideItem( name );
        }
    }

    if ( !counter[ CKEDITOR.STYLE_BLOCK ] )
        this.hideGroup( lang[ 'panelTitle' + String( CKEDITOR.STYLE_BLOCK ) ] );

    if ( !counter[ CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE ] )
        this.hideGroup( lang[ 'panelTitle' + String( CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE ) ] );

    if ( !counter[ CKEDITOR.STYLE_OBJECT ] )
        this.hideGroup( lang[ 'panelTitle' + String( CKEDITOR.STYLE_OBJECT ) ] );
},
onClick: function( value ) {
    editor.focus();
    editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );

    var style = styles[ value ],
        type = style._.type,
        selection = editor.getSelection(),
        selectedElement = selection.getSelectedElement(),
        selectedRanges = !selectedElement && selection.getRanges(),
        selectedText = !selectedElement && selection.getSelectedText(),
        element;

    if(type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_OBJECT && (selectedElement || selectedText))
        element = !selectedText ? selectedElement : selectedText;

    else if((type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_BLOCK || type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE) && !selectedText && !selectedElement && selectedRanges[ 0 ] && selectedRanges[ 0 ].getCommonAncestor( 1 )) 
        element = selectedRanges[ 0 ].getCommonAncestor( 1 ).getAscendant( style.element );

    else if(type == CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE && selectedText && !selectedElement)
        element = selectedText;

    if(element != null) {
        var classes = !selectedText ? element.getAttribute( 'class' ) : null,
            classArr = classes != null ? classes.split(' ') : [],
            selClass = style._.definition.attributes['class'],
            styleClasses = CKEDITOR.tools.clone( style );

        if(classArr.length > 0 && contains(classArr, selClass) && !selectedText) {
            var newClassArr = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i < classArr.length; i++) {
                if(classArr[i] != selClass)
                    newClassArr.push(classArr[i]);
            }

            if(newClassArr.length == 0) {
                editor.removeStyle( styleClasses );
            }
            else {
                styleClasses._.definition.attributes['class'] = newClassArr.join(' ');
                editor.applyStyle( styleClasses );
            }
        }
        else {
            classArr.push(selClass);
            styleClasses._.definition.attributes['class'] = classArr.join(' ');
            editor.applyStyle( styleClasses );
        }
    }

    editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
},
```

It works for block elements and images (didn't checked fake elements), you can select and deselect all classes you want. But I have some trouble with inline elements.

If I click inside a block element, it lists all classes for this element and I can select/deselect what I want/need. If I click inside an inline element, nothing happends. Can getAscendant() not find inline element tags?

If I select text, it lists all classes for inline elements. But I want span classes only and not e.g. strong classes. Classes for the strong tag should only available if I select a strong element. Is it possible? How can I differentiate different inline elements?

Why anchors are objects and not inline elements? If I double click an anchor and close the link dialog, I can select an anchor class.

How to disable the combo, if no classes are available? I can not find the right place.
How to disable the combo close on a class selection? If the selected class is set after close, forget this question - I can live with it :-)

Here is a demo: http://webutler.de/test/index.php?lang=en

The complete file: test/plugins/cssclasscombo/plugin.js

The plugin as zip: test/plugins/cssclasscombo.zip

If you try the plugin, set

```
config.contentsCss = ['contents.css']; // <= it reads the classes from this file
config.extraPlugins = 'cssclasscombo';
config.removePlugins = 'stylescombo';
config.stylesSet = [];
config.allowedContent = true;
// the plugin works with indent and justify classes =>
config.justifyClasses = [ 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'alignjustify' ];
config.indentClasses = [ 'indent1', 'indent2', 'indent3', 'indent4', 'indent5' ];
```

to your config and use this CSS file: http://www.webutler.de/test/contents.css

Thanx for help

Comment: Made some updates, but it seems not possible to add/remove classes to/from inline elements.

Comment: Sometimes I'm stupid, simply I can use addClass / removeClass for inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but the plugin works now. If you can need it, here is the download:

http://webutler.de/download/ckeditor_plugins/cssclasscombo.zip

Settings in your config.js:

```
config.removePlugins = 'stylescombo';
config.extraPlugins = 'cssclasscombo';
config.stylesSet = [];
config.contentsCss = ['contents.css']; // <= classes are read from this file(s)
```